# jQuery context menu get clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, contextmenu

I am using [jQuery context menu plugin by Chris Domigan](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/) to appy a context menu. This is how I do it:

```
$('#contacts tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu1', {
    bindings: {
        'copy': function(t) {
             alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Copy');
         },

        'delete': function(t) {
             alert('Trigger was '+t.id+'\nAction was Delete');
        }
    },             
});
```

My question is, how do I get the content of the clicked tr item? I tried with

```
$(t.target).html()
```

but it returns `null`. Any idea?

**EDIT:** here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/gqhRV/

Comment: thats really vague please include your html, even better create a jsFiddle!

Comment: show some HTML, I'm guessing you're doing something abnormal

Comment: here is the example code http://jsfiddle.net/gqhRV/

Comment: when I add an id to your tr tag, that's what value comes back in the copy popup.  not quite what the documentation suggests.

Comment: why your link(plugin) is redirecting to a kitchen's site?

Comment: @ChandanKumarThakur this link is 8 years old o.O Seems to have changed

Comment: @ArtjomZabelin okay :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not familiar with the plugin, but from the looks of it you should be able to write:

```
$("#" + t.id).html();
```

but in the case of most jQuery plugins you should be able to do this:

```
$(this).html();
```

from within the context of the `'copy': function(t) {` and `'delete': function(t) {`

---

```
$('#contacts tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu1', {
    bindings: {
        'open': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Open"); },
        'email': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Email"); },
        'save': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Save"); },
        'delete': function(t) { ShowAction(t, "Delete"); }
    }
});

function ShowAction(t, a) {
    alert('Trigger was ' + t.id + '\nAction was ' + a + "\nHtml is " + $(t).html());
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dNUgg/

I'm guessing your `<tr>` tags do not have an `id` attribute

---

Even when the `<tr>` does not have an ID this still works: http://jsfiddle.net/dNUgg/1/

---

```
 alert('content is ' + $(t).text() + '\nAction was Delete');
```

updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqhRV/1/

you were doing `$(t.target).text()` when you should be doing `$(t).text()`

Answer (score 9):

I think is this what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.flexme1 tbody tr', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
        alert("Clicked on " + key + " on element " + options.$trigger.attr('id').substr(3));            
    },
    items: {
        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
        "sep1": "---------",
        "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
    }
});

$('.flexme1 tbody tr').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked', this);
})
});
</script>
```

It's integrated with the Flexigrid... works fine for me...

And obviously i have some extra options.

Comment: How is this not the selected answer?  Simplest solutions.  Just use options.$trigger.